# Can't run the program because Loading Devices in emulator is not running on Android Studio

Tags: java, android

I just downloaded Android Studio because I have a school assignment. I was given the task to create an application. I've downloaded the emulator and also the OS is at least **5.0 (Lollipop)**. When I first run Android Studio, the app runs. Then a few days later I reopened. My emulator "Loading Devices" has no Devices running.

[image: Android Studio Loading Devices]

What is the solution to that? Does anyone know a solution for such a case? I have tried **Invalidate Cache** and the problem is still the same. Can anyone help?

Comment: Try creating new emulator using  AVD

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete the old emulator and recreate new emulator by Devices Manager.

Comment: Already, I reinstalled Android Studio so all packages and Android Studio latest version